# How to render frames in game loop using model matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, transform, game-engine, vertex-shader

I'm developing a very basic 3d game engine.my game loop is something like this:

```
void draw()
{
   shader->bindShader();
   for(entity in entityList)
   {
      mat4 modelMat=entity.getModelMat();
      shader->sendUniform("model_matrix",&modelMat);//sending model matrix to shader
      glDraw(...)//draw call
   }
}
void gameLoop()
{
   init();
   draw();//drawing objects for the first time
   while(true)//game loop
   {
       handlingEvents();//calculate model matrices based on inputs
       renderScene();//this function renders the scene on current frame
   }
}
```

and here is my vertex shader:

```
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;
uniform mat4 model_matrix;

void main()
{
gl_Position = projection_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vec4(gl_Vertex.xyz,1);
}
```

currently i'm rendering the scene by simply clear everything and draw them again with new model matrices.So my question is is there a way to update each object without clearing and drawing whole scene on every frame?

Comment: I think your question may be too broad.  Are you currently experiencing any particular slowdown?  There are a lot of optimizations that you can do like stencil buffers, entity culling based on view, distance, etc.  The thing is that you shouldn't bring these sorts of things in until you need them because they may not even pay off.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".  If I remember right, there was an in-depth article discussing how Wind Waker didn't even have that much culling.  They did a wireframe render showing that everything was rendered every frame.

Comment: *"is is there a way to update each object without clearing and drawing whole scene"* - No, in general not.

Comment: @zero298 no everything is just fine right now.but i thought its not usual to do things this way, so i asked